# Gradle task assembleDebug failed while sync with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you added `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` this dependency in build.gradle?

Comment: add ur build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

instead of:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'`

Comment: `firebase-core` no longer needed! Check out the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). `firebase-analytics` willl work.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but some people are having problems with `firebase-analytics` which can all be solved by using `firebase-core:16.0.1` instead.